# How to return an ArrayList of tree nodes spanning from the tree root to a target using recursion?

Tags: java, java-8

This goal of this project is to analyze who benefits who in a pyramid scheme. PyramidScheme.java is a data structure which extends LinkedTree (LinkedTree.java is a very standard tree class), passing in Person (a Person.java is a participant in the pyramid scheme, class information is irrelevant) objects in place of the generic.

The method in question that I cannot figure out is findNodeChain. This method, a member of PyramidScheme.java, is supposed to return an ArrayList of MultiTreeNode (MultiTreeNode.java is a very standard tree-node class) objects, being the people "who benifit" from the sucker - i.e., every node above the sucker. Here is the relevant code (findNodeChain is at the bottom):

```
 /**
 * Initiates the recursive findNodeChain method to return a list of all
 * nodes that are above the node containing the target. This overload takes
 * a Person.
 *
 * @param sucker the individual from whom others above are benefitting
 * @return an ArrayList of individuals higher up in the hierarchy
 */
public ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>>
        whoBenefits(Person sucker) {
    return findNodeChain(root, sucker);
}

/**
 * Initiates the recursive findNodeChain method to return a list of all
 * nodes that are above the node containing the target. This overload takes
 * a MultiTreeNode.
 *
 * @param sucker the individual from whom others above are benefitting
 * @return an ArrayList of individuals higher up in the hierarchy
 */
public ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>>
        whoBenefits(MultiTreeNode<Person> sucker) {
    return findNodeChain(root, sucker.getElement());
}

/**
 * Similar to findNode, but rather than returning the node that contains the
 * target, instead returns a list of nodes above the one that contains the
 * target, in low to high level order.
 *
 * @param node the current node being examined
 * @param target the Person being searched for
 * @return an ArrayList of nodes that are directly above the target in the
 * hierarchy
 */
private ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>>
        findNodeChain(MultiTreeNode<Person> node, Person target) {
    return findNodeChain(node, target, new ArrayList<>());
}

/**
 * Primary helper method for findNodeChain
 *
 * @param node the current node being examined
 * @param target the Person being searched for
 * @param helper the ArrayList people to be returned
 * @return an ArrayList of nodes that are directly above the target in the
 * hierarchy
 */
private ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>>
        findNodeChain(MultiTreeNode<Person> node, Person target, ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>> helper) {
    if (node.getElement().equals(target)) { 
        // If this node is the target, add it to the list and return.
        helper.add(node); 
        return helper;
    } else {            
        //For each child of this node...
        for (MultiTreeNode<Person> child : node.getChildren()) {
            //...Call this method, seeing if the child can find our target.
            helper.add(child);
            helper = findNodeChain(child, target, helper);
            //If it isn't null, then the child has found our target, and...
            if (helper.get(helper.size() - 1) != null) {
                return helper; //...The target is passed upwards.
            }
        }
        // If none of the children have the target, return the passed ArrayList
        return helper;
    }
}
```

I started trying to solve this by basing findNodeChain() off the findNode() method in LinkedTree.java:

```
/**
 * Finds the node that contains a target element. Calls the recursive
 * overload to search for target.
 *
 * @param target the element being searched for
 * @return the MultiTreeNode containing the target, or null if not found
 */
public MultiTreeNode<T> findNode(T target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return findNode(root, target);
}

/**
 * Finds the node that contains a target element. This checks the current
 * node, and if it is the target, returns it. Otherwise, it recursively
 * checks each of the current node's children, to see if they can find it.
 * If none of this node's children can find it either, then null is
 * returned.
 *
 * @param node the node currently being examined
 * @param target the element being searched for
 * @return the MultiTreeNode containing the target, or null if not found
 */
private MultiTreeNode<T> findNode(MultiTreeNode<T> node, T target) {
    //If this node is the one holding the target...
    if (node.getElement().equals(target)) {
        return node; //...Return this node, so it is passed upwards.
    } else { //Otherwise...
        MultiTreeNode<T> temp;
        //For each child of this node...
        for (MultiTreeNode<T> child : node.getChildren()) {
            //...Call this method, seeing if the child can find our target.
            temp = findNode(child, target);
            //If it isn't null, then the child has found our target, and...
            if (temp != null) {
                return temp; //...The target is passed upwards.
            }
        }
        //If none of the children found the target, return null.
        return null; //This signifies that no target was found.
    }
}
```

Have also tried this:

```
/**
 * Similar to findNode, but rather than returning the node that contains the
 * target, instead returns a list of nodes above the one that contains the
 * target, in low to high level order.
 *
 * @param node   the current node being examined
 * @param target the Person being searched for
 * @return an ArrayList of nodes that are directly above the target in the
 * hierarchy
 */
private ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>>
findNodeChain(MultiTreeNode<Person> node, Person target) {
    // Create the ArrayList here and pass its reference at each recursion
    ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>> helper = new ArrayList<>();
    hasNodeChain(node, target, helper); // Pass the ArrayList
    return helper; // Return the passed around ArrayList. Yay for pass by reference!!

}

/**
 * Primary helper method for findNodeChain
 *
 * @param node   the current node being examined
 * @param target the Person being searched for
 * @param helper the pointer of the ArrayList of people to be returned
 * @return true if there is a path from node to target, false if not
 */
private boolean hasNodeChain(MultiTreeNode<Person> node, Person target, ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>> helper) {
    helper.add(node); // Assume this node is a member of the list.
    if (node.getElement().equals(target)) { // If the node we're at equals the target, return it.
        return true;
    } else {
        for (MultiTreeNode<Person> child : node.getChildren()) { // For each child in the node, recurse the method.
            if (hasNodeChain(child, target, helper)) { // If a child has a path, this node is a member of the list.
                return true;
            }
        }
        // If none of the children are members, remove this node.
        helper.remove(helper.size() - 1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think that I am close to figuring this out, but not quite there. What I have just adds every element in the tree :(. Could anyone provide some guidance please?

Comment: `helper.add(child);` since you are doing this unconditionally, and making a recursive call unconditionally, of course this ends up adding every node to the list. You need to add `child` to the list only on the condition that `child` is really an ancestor of `target`.

Comment: Right, but what is that condition? (Logically) How do I ensure that child is an ancestor of the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of ancestors of a node on `MultiTreeNode`, your recursive calls need to pass a reference list to itself which would only be initialized not by the `recursion where the target was found` but by the `callee that triggered the recursion`. See below snippet.

```
 private boolean isParentOfTarget(MultiTreeNode<Person> suspect, Person target, 
  ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>> chain) { 
    // Check whether the suspect is the target
    if (suspect.getElement().equals(target)) { 
       // Suspect is actually the target :|
       // No need to append to chain here!
       return true; //just head home
    } 
    else {             
       // Yet to find the target. So we check the children of the suspect
       for (MultiTreeNode<Person> child : suspect.getChildren()) {
         // The children may also have children
         // Hence we do a recursive call 
         if(isParentOfTarget(child, target, chain)){
          // Suspect is guilty :)
          chain.add(suspect); 
          return true; //head home
         } 
         // ...At this point
         // Johnny is still lost... Continue Search!
       } 
       return false; //Suspect not guilty :(
     }
 }
```

Usage

```
ArrayList<MultiTreeNode<Person>> chain = new ArrayList<>();
Boolean is_pot = isParentOfTarget(root_node,target_person,chain);
if(is_pot){
 // ... A relation exist between root_node and target_person
 // Chain contains all parents of target_person excluding root_node
}
else{
 // ... Root_node and target_person exists in two different worlds
 // Chain is a blank slate
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I hope this helps you.

The condition on which the node should be added is whether or not the node is on the path to the node you are looking for.

So if I understand correctly, you can do something like this (only not a simplified example like I have made it):

```
private ArrayList<T> findNodeChain() {
    if (findNode(node) != null) { 
        // If this node is the on the path to our node, add it to the list and return.
        helper.add(node); 
        return helper;
    } else {            
        // If none of the children have the target, 
        //there must not be a path or the node is at the end
        return helper;
      }
 }
```

Take a look at [This Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-path-root-given-node-binary-tree/) to understand what I am trying to explain. I actually wrote out the C# code they have, and I think it would be helpful for you to look at the Java example.

Comment: I followed that link, and this scenario made more sense to me... I attempted to do something similar to the printed list, but am still getting the same results. What logical piece and I missing? Check the original question again (last chunk of code) to see what I am currently trying to do.